# Object methods in C: memory leaks

Tags: c, pointers, object, struct, memory-leaks

I have questions about how to properly implement objects in C.

Is the fact that I return objects from methods more prone to memory leaks than, for example, never returning an object and doing it by reference in the argument list like this?

```
extern void quaternion_get_product(Quaternion * this, Quaternion * q, Quaternion * result);
```

This way the `malloc()` call is only done in the constructor, so it is easier to control.

I am new to this kind of encapsulation in C, so I am not sure if this would be the way to solve my problem. I just want my code to be scalable, and I see that if I continue doing this, memory leaks are going to be all around, and it is going to be really hard to debug. How is it usually approached? Am I on the right track with my code?

My question is, if I have this:

```
Quaternion p = *quaternion_create(1, 0, 0, 0);
Quaternion q = *quaternion_create(1, 0, 1, 0);
Quaternion r = *quaternion_create(1, 1, 1, 0);
Quaternion s = *quaternion_create(1, 1, 1, 1);

p = *quaterion_get_product(&p, &q); // Memory leak, old p memory block is not being pointed by anyone

Quaternion t = *quaternion_get_product(&q, quaternion_get_product(&s, &r));
```

Memory leaks are present when nesting function calls, intermediate memory blocks are not pointed by any existing pointer, cannot call quaternion_destroy

**Header file:**

```
#ifndef __QUATERNIONS_H_
#define __QUATERNIONS_H_

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Quaternion Quaternion;

struct Quaternion {
    float w;
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

extern Quaternion *quaternion_create(float nw, float nx, float ny, float nz);
extern void quaternion_destroy(Quaternion *q);
extern Quaternion *quaternion_get_product(Quaternion *this, Quaternion *q);
extern Quaternion *quaternion_get_conjugate(Quaternion *this);
extern float quaternion_get_magnitude(Quaternion *this);
extern void quaternion_normalize(Quaternion *this);
extern Quaternion *quaternion_get_normalized(Quaternion *this);
#endif
```

**Implementation file:**

```
#include "quaternion.h"
#include <math.h>

Quaternion *quaternion_create(float nw, float nx, float ny, float nz) {
    Quaternion *q = malloc(sizeof(Quaternion));

    q->w = nw;
    q->x = nx;
    q->y = ny;
    q->z = nz;
    return q;
}

void quaternion_destroy(Quaternion *q) {
    free(q);
}

Quaternion *quaternion_get_product(Quaternion *this, Quaternion *p) {
        Quaternion *return_q = quaternion_create(
            this->w * p->w - this->x * p->x - this->y * p->y - this->z * p->z,  // new w
            this->w * p->x + this->x * p->w + this->y * p->z - this->z * p->y,  // new x
            this->w * p->y - this->x * p->z + this->y * p->w + this->z * p->x,  // new y
            this->w * p->z + this->x * p->y - this->y * p->x + this->z * p->w
        );
        return return_q;
}

Quaternion *quaternion_get_conjugate(Quaternion *this)
{
        return quaternion_create(this->w, -this->x, -this->y, -this->z);
}

float quaternion_get_magnitude(Quaternion *this) {
        return sqrt(this->w * this->w + this->x * this->x + this->y * this->y + this->z * this->z);
}

void quaternion_normalize(Quaternion *this) {
        float m = quaternion_get_magnitude(this);
        this->w /= m;
        this->x /= m;
        this->y /= m;
        this->z /= m;
}

Quaternion *quaternion_get_normalized(Quaternion *this) {
        Quaternion *r = quaternion_create(this->w, this->x, this->y, this->z);
        quaternion_normalize(r);
        return r;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to emulate objects in c? wouldn't c++ be easier?

Comment: I'd not use malloc/free at all, mainly because of lower performance because malloc/free are rather expensive operations.

Comment: Just a side comment. I suspect that you're implementing quaternions to do math in something that might be performance sensitive. The constant mallocs will absolutely destroy your performance. A decent answer of how to avoid memory leaks and not destroy your performance at the same time is: don't malloc. Avoid mallocs at all costs, let the user deal with allocations and frees.

Comment: I will tell you one thing, your pointer spacing makes it hard to debug as does your multiplication like `this->x*p->y`.  You've put spaces where they didn't belong and removed them from where they did. You want to visually associate things to enhance clarity and not cram things together either.  Generally except for pointers, there is white space (one space) on either side of an operator.

Comment: How am I supposed to create this kind of objects without using malloc?

Comment: I can't see from your code that `get_product` would intrinsically create a memory leak - Just like a copy constructor in C++ doesn't necessarily create a memory leak. I cannot see a good reason as well why you pass a *pointer to a pointer* into `get product` - Simply leave responsibility for the original object to the caller and you're done.

Comment: Took me too many edits to get it looking right, but I'm done with the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it can get even worse if some function has *both* side effect of updating something and return a newly constructed value. Say, who remembers that `scanf` returns a value?

Looking at [GNU Multi Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/) I'd suggest that the following is one reasonable solution (actually, they go even further by making memory allocation user's headache, not library's):

1. Only a constructor can create a new object. I'd also suggest that all constructors' name follow the same pattern.
2. Only a destructor can destroy an already existing object.
3. Functions take both input arguments (say, two sides of `+`) and output argument(s) (where to put the result, overriding everything that was in the object before), like this:

`mpz_add (a, a, b); /* a=a+b */`

That way you will always clearly see when objects are created/destroyed and can ensure that there are no leaks or double frees. Of course, that prevents you from "chaining" multiple operations together and makes you manually manage temporary variables for intermediate results. However, I believe you'd still have to do that manually in C, because even compiler does not know much about dynamically allocated variable's lifetime.

Actually, if we leave no. 3 and add the "library does not manage memory" clause, we will get even more error-prone solution (from library's point of view), which will require library's user to manage memory however they want. That way you also don't lock user with `malloc`/`free` memory allocation, which is kind of good thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to dynamically allocate your quaterions. A quaternion has a fixed size and therefore you can use just plain Quaternions. If you make integer calculations you also use just `int`s without dynamically allocating space for each `int`.

Idea for not using `malloc/free` (untested code)

```
Quaternion quaternion_create(float nw, float nx, float ny, float nz) {
    Quaternion q;

    q.w = nw;
    q.x = nx;
    q.y = ny;
    q.z = nz;
    return q;
}

Quaternion quaternion_get_product(Quaternion *this, Quaternion *p) {
    Quaternion return_q = quaternion_create(
        this->w * p->w - this->x * p->x - this->y * p->y - this->z * p->z,  // new w
        this->w * p->x + this->x * p->w + this->y * p->z - this->z * p->y,  // new x
        this->w * p->y - this->x * p->z + this->y * p->w + this->z * p->x,  // new y
        this->w * p->z + this->x * p->y - this->y * p->x + this->z * p->w
    );
    return return_q;
}
```

Usage

```
Quaternion p = quaternion_create(1, 0, 0, 0);
Quaternion q = quaternion_create(1, 0, 1, 0);
Quaternion r = quaternion_create(1, 1, 1, 0);
Quaternion s = quaternion_create(1, 1, 1, 1);

p = quaterion_get_product(&p, &q);

Quaternion t = quaternion_get_product(&q, quaternion_get_product(&s, &r));
```

There are no `malloc`s nor `free`s so there is no possible memory leak and the performance will be better.

Comment: Wow, this is what I didn't think of... I knew there was an elegant way. I cannot see right now any potential problems this may raise with scalability, any of you see any problems?

Comment: Destructor?... Maybe it will only have code when one of the members of the Quaternion struct is a pointer to some array or struct?

Comment: @Angel you don't need any destructors with this approach.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, and what about the fact that that way we are creating a struct inside the constructor and then copying it outside and removing the copy inside after, how is this efficiency-wise compared to the malloc()? What if the struct was really big?

Comment: @Angel you are right, if the struct is really big, then copying around might be a performance problem. But be aware that _removing the copy inside_ doesn't take any time. The cost for allocating and deallocating local variables is zero (at least in all implementations I know).

Comment: Ok Michael, thanks for this approach, by far the one I like the most syntax-wise. I am a bit scared about performance though. I am now doubting between your approach and @yeputons approach. But obviously I stopped liking my approach. Also look at this book https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf I didnt read it, but peeking around I see that they use malloc() approach in constructor...

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're calling it wrong.

You also need to check to see if malloc() returns NULL and handle that failure (such as by displaying an out of memory error message and exiting if it fails because that's non-recoverable generally).

**UPDATE:**

Since YOU need to free your intermediate result you have to take more action to retain the pointer.

**UPDATE 2**

@MichaelWalz approach is great. Why deal with all the allocations and pointer management if you don't need to?  However, if you *do* use pointers and allocate memory you have to retain pointers and make sure you free things and pass them around/reuse them carefully. I've updated my example to handle the nested call.

**UPDATE 3**

I had to remove the &'s from the function call arguments because you're passing pointers in, which are already the address of what you want to point to.  You didn't assign the output of the functions properly. Notice how the pointer assignments are different in the fixed example too.

---

```
Quaternion p = *quaternion_create(1, 0, 0, 0);
Quaternion q = *quaternion_create(1, 0, 1, 0);
Quaternion r = *quaternion_create(1, 1, 1, 0);
Quaternion s = *quaternion_create(1, 1, 1, 1);

p = *quaterion_get_product(&p, &q); // Memory leak, old p memory block is not being pointed by anyone

Quaternion t = *quaternion_get_product(&q, quaternion_get_product(&s, &r));
```

---

```
Quaternion *p = quaternion_create(1, 0, 0, 0);
Quaternion *q = quaternion_create(1, 0, 1, 0);
Quaternion *r = quaternion_create(1, 1, 1, 0);
Quaternion *s = quaternion_create(1, 1, 1, 1);


Quaternian *tmp = quaterion_get_product(p, q); 
quaternian_destroy(p);
p = tmp;
tmp = quaternion_get_product(s, r)
Quaternion *t = quaternion_get_product(q, tmp); 
quaternian_destroy(tmp);
```

Comment: ugh... took me some tries but I think the example does more what you want based on your example of use.